# Internal in PMML

Tags: pmml

I'm currently working on a program that generates a PMML file. I'm starting with decision tree model.
In the PMML website, in a example of tree model, I see this:

```xml
<Internal closure="closedClosed" leftMargin="4.3" rightMargin="4.4"/>
```

What is this this `Internal` node ? What does closure, or Margin refers to ?

Comment: http://www.cse.yorku.ca/tdb/_doc.php/userg/sw/weka/doc/weka/core/pmml/FieldMetaInfo.Interval.Closure.html

Comment: http://www.dmg.org/v4-1/Transformations.html

Comment: Ok I'm definitly dumb. Thanks

Comment: No, everyone has a start somewhere to perfection :)